# Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.stringSerializationFailed

Tags: ios, alamofire, multipartform-data

I'm updating the user profile in which there are text fields and a UIImage View. Here is the image of how a successful call looks like:
[image]

I'm sending call as:

```
let headers = [
                "Authorization": "Bearer \(pDefault.object(forKey: "accessToken")!)",
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Accept" : "application/json"
            ]
            let url = "\(baseURL)profile?_method=put"

            let parameters = [
                "name": self.nameOfUser.text ?? "",
                "date_of_birth": dateOfBirth.text ?? "",
                "address": self.userAddress.text ?? "",
                "gender": "\(self.selectedGender ?? 0)",
                "city": "\(self.selectedCity ?? 0)"
                ] as [String : Any]

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:{ multipartFormData in

                    for key in parameters.keys {
                            let name = String(key)
                            if let val = parameters[name] as? String{
                                multipartFormData.append(val.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: name)
                            }
                    }

                    multipartFormData.append(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.userDisplayPic.image!, 1)!, withName: "avatar")},
                                 usingThreshold:UInt64.init(),
                                 to:url,
                                 method:.post,
                                 headers:headers,
                                 encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                                    switch encodingResult {
                                    case .success(let upload, _, _):
                                        upload.responseString { response in
                                            debugPrint(response)
                                        }
                                    case .failure(let encodingError):
                                        print(encodingError)
                                    }
                })
            }
        }
```

If I change `responseString` to `responseJSON` I get this error:

> FAILURE:
>   responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character
>   0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

and if I keep it the way it is in the code I get

> Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.stringSerializationFailed

A successful response on postman shows this:
[image]

**UPDATE**

I added this:

```
let total:Int! = response.data?.count
                                            for index in 0...total {
                                                if let substr = String.init(data: response.data!.subdata(in: Range(0..<(total-index))), encoding: .utf8) {
                                                    print("substr: \(substr)")
                                                }
                                            }
```

in `upload.responseJSON { response in` and I get this error exception:

> [] nw_socket_output_finished shutdown(12, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not
>   connected substr: ErrorException: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL
>   server has gone away in E:\Hayaat\htdocs\hayaat...

and then this code goes on and lastly it ends on:

> Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: PDOStatement::execute():
>   MySQL server has gone away (SQL: update `users` set `avatar` =

Comment: Could you get `print("response.data: \(response.data as Data))`?

Comment: @Larme it printed `10510 bytes`

Comment: Sorry, `as NSData` instead. In other words, your response is sending back data, but it's not a valid String, and neither a JSON. Is it an image?

Comment: @Larme It's JSON I've also added the successful response in question and by doing NSData it gives me a long string which starts like `<4572726f 72457863 65707469 6f6e3a20`

Comment: Strangely, `<4572726f 72457863 65707469 6f6e3a20>` gives `ErrorException:` as a message.

Comment: Maybe to help, an not really pretty thing, but could help debugging: `let total:Int! = data?.count for index in 0...total { if let substr = String.init(data: data!.subdata(in: Range(0..<(total-index))), encoding: .utf8) {print("substr: \(substr)")}}` where `let data = response.data`. It could help you find more about your issue printing part of the message, and help you find the index where the data is not a string valid anymore.

Comment: @Larme by applying your last comment in the code I got an error exception: `ErrorException: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in `E:\Folder\htdocs\....` and then some long code and lastly `Next Illuminate\Database\QueryException: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away (SQL: update `users` set `avatar` = ` and in the start it is also showing `Socket is not connected`

Comment: Your server is saying there is an error. You need to check what's the issue between the POSTMAN request and yours. I'm wondering what's the size of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.userDisplayPic.image!, 1)`. You use a threshold (I think that it's to limite the size?), could you check by reducing the quality of the image, or maybe the size, at 20*20 for instance, and a lower quality (not `1`).

Comment: @Larme in a discussion with the backend guy he told me that `expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in` means you are not sending the valid path for the file. However the key value for image is `avatar` which I've provided in the `multipartFormData.append` and not in the parameters.